# How to extract the values which is having specified length

Tags: python, list, dictionary

A dictionary is below

```
my = [{'Name':'Super', 'Gender':'Male', 'UNNO':111234},
      {'Name':'Spider', 'Gender':'Male', 'UNNO':11123},
      {'Name':'Bat', 'Gender':'Female', 'UNNO':113456},
     {'Name':'pand', 'Gender':'Female', 'UNNO':13456}]
```

The unique number is the value for key "UNNO" for each dictionary.

All UNNO numbers must contain 6 digits.

UNNO number start from `11` is only valid

Expected out

```
#my_dict = {'Male':{'Super':111234}, 'Female':{'Bat':113456}}
#my_dict_list = {'Male':['Super'], 'Female':['Bat']}
```

Pseudo Code

```
d = {'Male':{}, 'Female':{}}
for i in my:
    if i['UNNO'].startswith('11') and len(i['UNNO'])= 6:
        d['Male'].append(i['Name'])
```

Comment: What's your question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solely based on your expected output, here's the code:

```
d = {}
for i in my:
    if str(i['UNNO']).startswith('11') and len(str(i['UNNO'])) == 6:
        # To get {'Male':['Super'], 'Female':['Bat']}
        d[i['Gender']] = [i['Name']]

        # To get {'Male':{'Super':111234}, 'Female':{'Bat':113456}}
        # d[i['Gender']] = {i['Name']: i['UNNO']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting it correctly you want to split my in male and female if the UNNO is valid? Though I have no idea what #my_dict is since it neither appears in the pseudo code nor matches the format of my. If I guessed correctly this way it makes a list of female and male entries in the d dictionary:

```
my = [{'Name':'Super', 'Gender':'Male', 'UNNO':111234},
  {'Name':'Spider', 'Gender':'Male', 'UNNO':11123},
  {'Name':'Bat', 'Gender':'Female', 'UNNO':113456},
 {'Name':'pand', 'Gender':'Female', 'UNNO':13456}]

d = {'Male':[], 'Female':[]}
for i in my:
    if str(i['UNNO'])[:2]=='11' and len(str(i['UNNO']))== 6:
        d[i['Gender']].append(i['Name'])
```